# Mock assigned to instance variable is null during Spock Groovy test

Tags: jenkins, groovy, spock

I am encountering a strange error with Spock when unit testing a Groovy class. In the test I am mocking a Jenkins CI class (not sure if relevant). During my test the `ctx` instance variable of `MyClass` is null so I get a `NullPointerException`, even though it is not null when created in the test ("when" feature).

Am I doing something wrong here? It appears that the mock object reference is cleared during the test. Below is a simplified example to illustrate:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript
import spock.lang.*

class MySpec extends Specification {

    def 'does something'() {
        given: 'valid input'
        def foo = 'foo'
       
        when: 'something happens'
        def context = createContext()
        assert context
        def obj = new MyClass(createContext())
        def success = obj.doSomething(foo)
        
        then: 'it is successful'
        assert success
    }

    private def createContext() {
        def ctx = Mock(CpsScript)
        ctx.sh(_) >> "sh called"
        return ctx
    }
}
```

```
class MyClass {

    private final def ctx

    MyClass(ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx
    }

    def doSomething(foo) {
        ctx.sh('// bash script that uses foo')
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJxlUrFywjAM3fMVui6OF9h7BwszEx_QM45C3AbbZzlAj-PfKzvEJNRLYunp6UnPuldEsPN00MH4CPcK-DTYAnW1V0Gd5RhKJ_88qkdV6Vy2_93l773KGR_MRUWE1ljVZw4db2Pqiaw5IOFFGDtDK47BJkNH-qKgcQd3RsbYU906Ny9k9IoFivUajoo6oFF97FSEgZCA8UL-13vwqAFvEW1DkC6mNVpF4-w0RGosGscUNDUX9bz1yVzQfoK4qN40YKwfoijJVM2teR6RFCzi7vjNcYvX1zYC8r52zkaWVEs5wUvZtcutihLolPdoaUlMg9bI421Si9X71pbujVvPrCaCoam4HfoXKWvDEKfU3JbJ4mzuUv1sRU_rWdDe6Z-6vC757t-XhO0WPthArfoem48CCBiHYGevggWUZDp_KtjEMw). I guess the problem is, that CpsScript doesn't have a `sh` method.

Comment: I don't get a `NoSuchMethodException`, I get `NullPointerException` meaning `ctx` is null.

Comment: Please post the full exception. Looking at https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-cps/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsScript.html you can see that it doesn't have the method, but instead makes use of Groovy's meta programing features.

Comment: The NPE does **not** mean that `ctx` is `null`, because it says: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "groovy.lang.Binding.getVariables()" because the return value of "groovy.lang.Script.getBinding()" is null`. Just print `ctx` before calling `ctx.sh()` in order to confirm that.